# Responsive media queries are not working with Gmail

Tags: gmail, html-email, responsive

I am writing some custom code in Mailchimp code block but for some reason Gmail on my phone is ignoring any media queries I add to the styles:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
<style>
    /* Nav menu */
.menu-container {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center !important
}
.menu-item {
 text-align:center !important;
 padding: 15px 0px;
 display:block;
 background-color:#000;
 width: 20%;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu-item:hover {
 background-color:#585f6a !important;
}

.menu-item a {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #fff !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}


.menu li:hover {
background-color: #585f6a !important;
}

/* Responsiveness */
@media screen (max-width:768px) {

  .menu-item {
    width:100% !important
  }
  
  .menu-item a {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
    
</style>

<div class="mcnTextContent">
        <!-- Menu -->

<div class="menu-container">
    <td class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><b>HOME</b></a></td>
    <td class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><b>SHOP</b></a></td>
    <td class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><b>ABOUT</b></a></td>
    <td class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><b>VIDEOS</b></a></td>
    <td class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><b>FORUMS</b></a></td>
</div>
```

I've tried many different solutions recommended on Stack but nothing I do seems to help resolve this issue.
If anyone has any idea to get this to work I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, there is no `<td>`. That's because there's no `<table>` or `<tr>` either. So it's not valid code. The td is being stripped. Every table needs those three elements to be valid.